# How to change button depending on received value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to show the success button if my value is less than 90, and show the warning button if the value is equal or greater than 90. The value is received in JS. The buttons are as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Warning">Server 1</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Normal">Server 2</button>
```

How can I enable/show and disable/hide a button depending on the value I'm receiving?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could probably use the [CSS display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to accomplish this.

Comment: What `value` are you referring to? In your example you give two buttons, do you want both to change depending on the `value` or only a specific button to change?

Comment: Would you do this with JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether or not your value is less than 90 and modify the `display` property of the buttons accordingly.

```
if(value < 90) {
    document.querySelector(".btn-warning").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".btn-success").style.display = null;
} else {
    document.querySelector(".btn-warning").style.display = null;
    document.querySelector(".btn-success").style.display = "none";
}
```

Instead of `.querySelector()`, you could also consider using IDs and `.getElementByID()`, or any other means of retrieving the elements. If you're using jQuery, this can be accomplished with the `.css()` method.